# Processing a completed checkbox [web2py]

Tags: python, html, web2py

Hi I'm a complete beginner so apologies if this is simple. I'm using web2py to create a 'simple' to do list. I want to be able to process the result from user interaction with a checkbox into my database but I've no idea how to make my page refresh and add the record in.

Table in question is:

```
db.define_table('todo',
                Field('completed', type='boolean', label='Completed', default=False))
```

This is currently represented in my views with:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="completed" value="{{=x.completed}}"></td>
```

I'm completely lost for ideas on how to make the result of user interaction with the checkbox update the master database - ideally as soon as someone clicks the checkbox it would update the database, please could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: That's quite a big question. Your view at the moment is just displaying data and you need a process to pass data back to the server. The simplest approach is to pass a FORM to your view. That would have a submit button to send the data back and update the database. If you want to update on click then you're looking at AJAX, which uses Javascript on the page to post information back to the server. This is more of a hint at what options you have than an answer :)

Comment: Hi David,
Thanks for the help. I've added a form to the view:  <form method="post",action="TaskCompletePost">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit", class='btn btn-success btn-sm', style='float:right'> and I have this saying:  def TaskCompletePost():
    vars=request.vars
    redirect(URL('index',vars = vars, args=['TaskCompletePost']))
    return However I'm still unsure of how to make the controller read the 'true' checkboxes and append them to the database :/ Apologies - very new to programming!!

Comment: I think you're missing the link between models, controller and views. The controller function for a page links your models to your views and is the main way to interact with data in the tables. So, rather than creating a pure HTML form in the views/, you use the controller to create the form and pass that to the view. The rendering process converts it to HTML but maintains a set of links that allows you to interact with it. Have a look at the minimal example in the web2py book here: http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#SQLFORM